# Python: pipelining functions with multiple return/input values, or use OOP? Best Practices?

Tags: python, function, oop, design-patterns

We have a data 'processing' function and a 'serializing' function. Currently the processor generates & returns 4 *different data structures* all from the same large data source input, and all outputs are related to each other.

Trying to separate out the 'data processing' from the 'serializing' step has gotten a bit.. messy. Looking for the best practise on what to do here.

```
def process(input):
   ...
   return a,b,c,d

def serialize(a,b,c):
   ...
   # Different serialization patterns for each of a-c.

a,b,c,d = process(input)
serialize(a,b,c)
go_on_to_do_other_things(d)
```

That feels janky.
Should I instead use a class where `a,b,c,d` are member variables?

```
class VeryImportantDataProcessor:
   def processd(self,input):
      self.a = ...
      self.b = ...
      ...

   def serialize(self):
      s3.write(self.a)
      convoluted_serialize(self.b)
      ...

vipd = VeryImportantDataProcessor()
vipd.process(input)
vipd.serialize()
```

Keen to hear your thoughts on what is best here!

Note after processing and serializing, the code goes on to use variable `d` for further unrelated shenanigans, but a, b, c are all finished once they've been saved. Not sure if that changes anything.